# Reusing frame widget in canvas after canvas.delete("all") doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, frame

I have created a frame within a canvas where I place checkbuttons with a mouse click. Selecting another radiobutton I run the command canvas.delete("all") to clear the canvas (and the frame with checkbuttons) and then create the frame again to continue placing checkbuttons. The frame gets created, but i can't place the checkbuttons anymore (I get no error messages either). Anybody knows why?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top_canvas = Canvas(root,width=676,height=768, bg='light blue')
top_canvas.pack()

frame = Frame(top_canvas, bg='light grey')
main_frame = top_canvas.create_window(500, 780, height = 1600, width = 600, window = frame)

def place_checkbutton_in_canvas(e):  # order to insert the checkbutton
    xx = e.x
    yy = e.y
    buttons = Checkbutton(frame)
    buttons.place(x=xx, y=yy)

def place_checkbutton():  #to run when checkbutton is selected. Now the checkbutton will be placed where mouse clicked if choose_line is selected
    frame.bind('<Button-1>', place_checkbutton_in_canvas)

def clear_canvas():
    top_canvas.delete("all")
    frame = Frame(top_canvas, bg='magenta')
    main_frame = top_canvas.create_window(500, 780, height=1600, width=600, window=frame)

chosen_option = IntVar()
choose_checkbutton = Radiobutton(root, text = "place checkbutton", variable=chosen_option, value = 1, command = place_checkbutton)
choose_checkbutton.place(x=10, y=10)
clear_button = Radiobutton(root, text = "clear everything", variable=chosen_option, value = 2, command = clear_canvas)
clear_button.place(x=10, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to delete all the items on canvas.You could use a list to save all of the checkbuttons,and use `.destroy()` to "delete" them:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top_canvas = Canvas(root,width=676,height=768, bg='light blue')
top_canvas.pack()
root.checkbutton_list = [] # initial a list

frame = Frame(top_canvas, bg='light grey')
main_frame = top_canvas.create_window(500, 780, height = 1600, width = 600, window = frame)

def place_checkbutton_in_canvas(e):  # order to insert the checkbutton
    xx = e.x
    yy = e.y
    buttons = Checkbutton(frame)
    buttons.place(x=xx, y=yy)
    root.checkbutton_list.append(buttons) # append the checkbutton to the list

def place_checkbutton():  #to run when checkbutton is selected. Now the checkbutton will be placed where mouse clicked if choose_line is selected
    frame.bind('<Button-1>', place_checkbutton_in_canvas)

def clear_canvas():
    for i in root.checkbutton_list:
        i.destroy() # destroy all the checkbuttons in the list
    root.checkbutton_list = [] # init it again

chosen_option = IntVar()
choose_checkbutton = Radiobutton(root, text = "place checkbutton", variable=chosen_option, value = 1, command = place_checkbutton)
choose_checkbutton.place(x=10, y=10)
clear_button = Radiobutton(root, text = "clear everything", variable=chosen_option, value = 2, command = clear_canvas)
clear_button.place(x=10, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

If you really want to use it with `.delete(ALL)`.You need to change the parent container of the checkbutton.I use `root.frame` to cover the previous frame.Like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top_canvas = Canvas(root,width=676,height=768, bg='light blue')
top_canvas.pack()

root.frame = Frame(top_canvas, bg='light grey')
main_frame = top_canvas.create_window(500, 780, height = 1600, width = 600, window = root.frame)

def place_checkbutton_in_canvas(e):  # order to insert the checkbutton
    xx = e.x
    yy = e.y
    buttons = Checkbutton(root.frame)
    buttons.place(x=xx, y=yy)

def place_checkbutton():  #to run when checkbutton is selected. Now the checkbutton will be placed where mouse clicked if choose_line is selected
    root.frame.bind('<Button-1>', place_checkbutton_in_canvas)

def clear_canvas():
    top_canvas.delete("all")
    root.frame = Frame(top_canvas, bg='magenta')
    main_frame = top_canvas.create_window(500, 780, height=1600, width=600, window=root.frame)

chosen_option = IntVar()
choose_checkbutton = Radiobutton(root, text = "place checkbutton", variable=chosen_option, value = 1, command = place_checkbutton)
choose_checkbutton.place(x=10, y=10)
clear_button = Radiobutton(root, text = "clear everything", variable=chosen_option, value = 2, command = clear_canvas)
clear_button.place(x=10, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is that this is part of a bigger program with more widgets. I could delete them individually, but it would be a lot of work. I was hoping it was a way using just canvas.delete("all")

Comment: @fernando "delete them individually".But you have used `delete("all")`. How could you do that? I would say `delete(all)` will delete all the item on the canvas,then you need to create a frame again which is unnessceary.

Comment: My need is to clear the canvas to start from scratch again. The frame is only because with delete("all"), the widgets in a canvas don't get removed, but in the frame they get removed. To create the frame again is only 2 lines. Delete all the widgets I place in it are a lot more.

Comment: @fernando Have you check the second part?

Comment: Sorry @jizhihaoSAMA, I missed it. I see it know, Its perfect, thank  you!!!